# IndentationError: expected an indented block 13

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
def count (a, e, i, o, u):
    a_length = len(a);
    e_length = len (e);
    i_length = len (i);
    o_length = len (o);
    u_length = len (u);

    total = 0;
    for i in range (a_lenght):
        if(a[i] == u[0]):
        end = i + u_length;

        if (a[i:end] == u):
        total +=1;
```

here is the error

ERROR Hide output

```
•  File "submission.py", line 11
    end = i + u_length;
  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: for one, `if:` should probably follow with a more indented line. You have zero difference here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add indentation to if blocks in python.

```
total = 0;
for i in range (a_lenght):
    if(a[i] == u[0]):
        end = i + u_length;

    if (a[i:end] == u):
        total +=1;
```